# Is there a way to change the type of the subcharts in c3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I have made a bar char chart and it also has a sub chart. I want to change the type of the subchart to line. As in, the main chart should be a bar chart but the subchart of this should be a line chart.

This is the piece of code I am using to generate the chart. But the type of subchart is not working.

```
var chart=c3.generate({
        bindto:bindTo(),
        data:{ 
            x:'x',
            /* value:['Percent DEP Enabled'],*/
            columns:data(),            
        type: 'bar'     
        },
        subchart: {
            show: true,
            size: {
            height: 25
            },

            },
        axis: {
                 x: {
                      type: 'timeseries',
                      tick: {
                      format: '%m-%d-%y',
                        rotate: -45,
                      },
                      height: 75
                  },/* y: {
                      tick: {
                          values: function(){
                                        jQuery.forEach(function(){

                                        })}
                          count: 8,
                          format:d3.format(".2s"),
                      },
        },*/
        subchart: {
            show: true,
            type: 'line',
            }
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because there is no setting like `axis.subchart`. When you take a look at the [reference](http://c3js.org/reference.html) you'll find everything you need but in your case there is no option.